# Java MySQL with prepared statement says parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I've looked on here before, but none of the answers helped me out!
I have the following code:

```
public void addSerialToDb(String serial) {
    System.out.println(serial);
    try{
        System.out.println(getMaxInt());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String serialV2 = ""+serial;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO blogdata.serials" + "VALUES(?, ?)");
        pst.setInt(1, getMaxInt());
        pst.setString(2, serialV2);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    closeDataBase();
}
```

In my database scheme, there are 2 columns, first one is integer (id) and second one is a VARCHAR(45) (serial). But still I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 0).
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3321)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3306)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4021)
>   at DataBase.SerialDataBase.addSerialToDb(SerialDataBase.java:41)

I used this method on another program, but since switched to IntelliJ it stopped working.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention, I'm using Java 1.8, the mySql connector 5.1.40 and running MySql 5.7.15

Comment: try adding a space before *VALUES* in the sql query that you are passing as parameter to `con.prepareStatement`

Comment: what is return from getMaxInt?

Comment: try making the sql query into a single string `INSERT INTO blogdata.serials VALUES(?, ?)`

Comment: `public int getMaxInt() throws SQLException{
        ResultSet rs;
        int id=-1;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(id) FROM blogdata.serials");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                id = rs.getInt("MAX(id)");
            }
            rs.close();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        return id+1;
    }`
Which works fine btw

Comment: @Blip I've done that before, didn't work either. I found on StackOverflow that some people suggested to use this method.

Comment: that's because your global variable pst is updated in getMaxInt() method.

Comment: that's why stack trace tell "2 > number of parameters, which is 0". try to fixed this issue and you will be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment **getMaxInt()** method, the problems is because of prepare statement object. It's being updated in **getMaxInt()** method and parameters not match error occurred. I think it's program logic error and you just need to change this program logic. I also recommend to not concat the String if it's not needed.

Below is just ok.

```
 pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO blogdata.serials (column1,column2) VALUES (?,?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the insert statement like this:

```
"INSERT INTO blogdata.serials (column1,column2) VALUES (?,?)";
```